# Populating a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to this and need help. 
I am making an agent based model for my thesis. 
What I am stuck on right now is birth and death in my population. 
I have a data.frame with male, female, age, preg, not preg and alive or dead. 
What I need to do is 
* For loop for n people- FOR EACH PERSON

- Decide sex using a random number (e.g., <0.5 = male)
- Decide age, draw a random number 0 to 80
- Set Alive to TRUE
- PREGO- for males and pre- or post-reproductive females, set to false
- For reproductive age females, roll the dice

I am also trying to store all this data in the data frame in order to create a starting poplulation for the simulation.

Like I said I just stared coding and I am getting stuck in the syntax, amongst other things
any help even resources that may help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

My answer, without loop(s):

```
#choose sample size and initialize dataframe with sex and age
samplesize <- 5000
df <- data.frame(sex = round(runif(samplesize)),
                 age = round(runif(samplesize, 0, 80)))

# all are alive and pregnant
df$alive <- TRUE
df$prego <- TRUE

# men and old/young women are not pregnant
df$prego[(df$sex == 1) | (df$age > 60) | (df$age < 14)] <- FALSE

# only some of the potentially pregnant women are pregnant
df$prego[df$prego == TRUE] <- sample(c(T,F), sum(df$prego), replace = T)

# replace 1s and 0s with M and F
df$sex[df$sex == 1] <- "M"
df$sex[df$sex == 0] <- "F"
```

Comment: Nice, super clean approach!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
library(data.table)

#starting variables
probMale <- .5
ageMin <- 0
ageMax <- 80
preProductiveAge <- 15
postProductiveAge <- 44
probPregnant <- .3
sampleSize <- 10000

listOut <- list()
for(i in 1:sampleSize){
  sex <- sample(c('male', 'female'), size = 1, prob = c(probMale, 1-probMale))
  age <- sample(0:80, size = 1)
  alive <- TRUE
  if(sex == 'male'){
    prego <- FALSE
  } else if(age >= postProductiveAge){
    prego <- FALSE
  } else if(age <= preProductiveAge){
    prego <- FALSE
  } else{
    prego <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1, prob = c(probPregnant, 1-probPregnant))
  }
  listOut[[i]] <- data.frame(sex = sex, age = age, alive = alive, prego = prego)
}

df <- rbindlist(listOut)
```

I kept the variables defined outside of the loop so you can modify easily.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me get started. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The unconditional variables are defined initially within `tibble()`.  The conditional variables are set in the subsequent `dplyr::mutate()` clause.

```
library(magrittr)
person_count          <- 20
range_fertile         <- c(20, 45)
possible_genders      <- c("male", "female")
possible_ages         <- 1:80
pregnant_probability  <- .14


tibble::tibble(
  gender          = sample(possible_genders , person_count, replace=T),
  age             = sample(possible_ages    , person_count, replace=T),
  alive           = TRUE
) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(
  is_fertile_age  = (gender=="female") & (range_fertile[1] <= age & age <= range_fertile[2]),
  is_pregnant     = (is_fertile_age & sample(c(T,F), person_count, prob = c(pregnant_probability, 1-pregnant_probability), replace=T))
)
```